# "Get $a$ and $B$ in terms of $m_1$, $m_2$": where $m_1 = aB / (a - 1)$ , $m_2 = ( aB^2 ) / (a - 2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have no idea how to solve this.
- I tried solving for B in terms of a and m1
- Then I plugged B into m2, but was not able to solve for a.

How do you do this  ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

This is the system of equations:

$\begin{align*}
 m_1 (a - 1)
   &= a B \\
 m_2 (a - 2)
   &= a B^2
\end{align*}$

Get $B$ from the first equation, replace in the second:

$\begin{align*}
  B
    &= \frac{m_1 (a - 1)}{a} \\
  m_2 (a - 2)
    &= a \left(\frac{m_1 (a - 1)}{a}\right)^2 \\
  m_2 a (a - 2)
    &= m_1^2 (a - 1)^2 \\
  m_2 a^2 - 2 m_2 a
    &= m_1^2 a^2 - 2 m_1^2 + m_1^2
\end{align*}$

This results in the quadratic:

$\begin{align*}
  (m_2 - m_1^2) a^2 - 2 (m_2 - m_1^2) a - m_1^2
    &= 0
\end{align*}$

Solve that one, replace in the expression for $B$.